# Package automated way of ReadProtecting all symbols

Tags: packages, attributes

My template for building packages has, at the end, the following expression that automatically `ReadProtect`s all symbols defined in my `pack`:

```
ToExpression[Names["pack`*"], InputForm, SetAttributes[#, {ReadProtected(*,Locked*)}] &]
```

It works fine, with the exception of cases where I define a constant, like for example: `iso=3;` This produces the following message (when loading the package):

```
SetAttributes::sym: Argument 3 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol. >>
```

Can the automated expression that sets `ReadProtected` be changed to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess would be this:

```
ToExpression[
   Names["pack`*"], 
   InputForm, 
   Function[sym,SetAttributes[sym, {ReadProtected(*,Locked*)}],HoldFirst] 
]
```

The problem is that functions defined with `# - &` notation do not hold their arguments.

Comment: Works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is undocumented so I don't know how stable it is. But worth to point this out.

- `SetAttributes` can work on strings if those strings are representing symbols that were already created.

Which is usually the case after running a package. moreover, those symbols don't have to have any type of value, just need to be created when read.

- The point is, you can just `` SetAttributes[#,Locked]& /@ Names["Context`*"] ``

So:

```
Quit[];
```

---

```
x;
SetAttributes["x", Locked]
Attributes@x
```

> ```
> {Locked}
> ```

But

```
Quit[];
```

---

```
SetAttributes["x", Locked]
Attributes@x
```

> ```
> SetAttributes["x", Locked]
> {}
> ```